# remove all characters between string and bracket in R

Tags: r, regex, gsub

Say I have a dataframe **df** in which a column **df$string**s contains strings like

```
[cat 00.04;09]
[cat 00.04;10]
```

and so on. I want to remove all characters between **"[cat**" and **"]"** to yield

```
[cat]
[cat]
```

I've tried this using gsub but it's not working and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong:

```
gsub('cat*?\\]', '', df)
```

Comment: To see what you are doing wrong, you should share your failing code with us.

Comment: Fair enough, I've added the bad code, thanks

Comment: It is really nasty, try `gsub('\\[cat.*?\\]', '[cat]', df$strings)`. Or `gsub('(\\[cat).*?(\\])', '\\1\\2', df$strings)`. Or `gsub('\\[cat[^]]*\\]', '[cat]', df$strings)`.

Comment: The first one I tried worked! Thank you very much!

Comment: It is almost the same as the one I posted, only the one below will also handle the cases when there are line breaks in between `[cat` and `]` and will work much faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `cat*?\\]` patten matches `ca`, then any 0+ `t` chars but as few as possible and then `]`.

You want to match any chars other than `]` between `[cat` and `]`:

```
gsub('\\[cat[^]]*\\]', '[cat]', df$strings)
```

Here,

- `\\[` - matches `[`
- `cat` - matches `cat`
- `[^]]*` - 0+ chars other than `]` (note that `]` inside the bracket expression should not be escaped when placed at the start - else, if you escape it, you will need to add `perl=TRUE` argument since PCRE regex engine can handle regex escapes inside bracket expressions (not the default TRE))
- `\\]` - a `]` (you do not even need to escape it, you may just use `]`).

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/qjZtw1):

```
x <- c("[cat 00.04;09]", "[cat 00.04;10]")
gsub('\\[cat[^]]*\\]', '[cat]', x)
## => [1] "[cat]" "[cat]"
```

If `cat` can be any word, use

```
gsub('\\[(\\w+)[^]]*\\]', '[\\1]', x)
```

where `(\\w+)` is a capturing group with ID=1 that matches 1 or more word chars, and `\\1` in the replacement pattern is a replacement backreference that stands for the group value.